# Failed While Installing Nokogiri on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, nokogiri

I am trying to install nokogiri on Ubuntu Linux. I am running Ruby-2.1.1. I have installed.

Output:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20181205-6502-3n3u4g.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.8.5/gem_make.out
```

Can anyone explain what I am missing?

Comment: It looks like you're missing ruby-dev, and maybe some others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing Ruby 2.1.1 with rbenv and set it as default version in ubuntu:

```
    rbenv install 2.1.1
    rbenv global 2.1.1
```

After installing ruby, install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
```

And then install nokogiri:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

This should do the trick...